Zeroing assembly register
I have a simple C function to add two arrays element-wise and store it in the first.
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

#define SIZE (1L << 16)

void test(uint8_t *  a ,  uint8_t *  b) {
  uint64_t i;

  for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
    a[i] += b[i];
  }
}

Now I generate x86-64 assembly code for this using clang, a part of which is below:
# %bb.0:
    #DEBUG_VALUE: test:a <- $rdi
    #DEBUG_VALUE: test:b <- $rsi
    #DEBUG_VALUE: test:i <- 0
    .loc    0 15 3 prologue_end             # example1.c:15:3
    leaq    65536(%rsi), %rax
    cmpq    %rdi, %rax
    jbe .LBB0_2
.Ltmp0:
# %bb.1:
    #DEBUG_VALUE: test:a <- $rdi
    #DEBUG_VALUE: test:b <- $rsi
    #DEBUG_VALUE: test:i <- 0
    leaq    65536(%rdi), %rax
    cmpq    %rsi, %rax
    jbe .LBB0_2
.Ltmp1:
# %bb.4:
    #DEBUG_VALUE: test:a <- $rdi
    #DEBUG_VALUE: test:b <- $rsi
    #DEBUG_VALUE: test:i <- 0
    .loc    0 0 3 is_stmt 0                 # example1.c:0:3
    xorl    %eax, %eax
.Ltmp2:
    .p2align    4, 0x90
.LBB0_5:                                # =>This Inner Loop Header: Depth=1
    #DEBUG_VALUE: test:a <- $rdi
    #DEBUG_VALUE: test:b <- $rsi
    #DEBUG_VALUE: test:i <- $rax
    .loc    0 16 13 is_stmt 1               # example1.c:16:13
    movzbl  (%rsi,%rax), %ecx
    .loc    0 16 10 is_stmt 0               # example1.c:16:10
    addb    %cl, (%rdi,%rax)
    

The first couple of sections is checking for address overlap between the two different arrays and then it starts with the element-wise addition(.LBB0_5 block). In the overlap check it uses the rax register and before the addition loop, it only clears the high 32-bits of this register, i.e eax(.Ltmp1 block).
Now in the addition block it uses the rax register as the counter but only the high 32-bit has been cleared. Shouldn't the whole rax register's 64 bits have been cleared before starting the element-wise addition?

Can you show the optimization flags/command you are using to compile this?

Writing to a 32 bit general purpose register clears the upper 32 bit of the corresponding 64 bit register.  So only clearing the low 32 bits is sufficient.  Clang prefers doing it that way as it saves a byte in the encoding.  See linked duplicate.

@fuz is this behavior only expected on 32-bit register or 16-bit/8-bit as well. Would writing to any of those clear the whole 64 bit register?

@Tarique Only writing to a 32 bit register clears the full register, 8 and 16 bit writes do not.

"it only clears the high 32-bits of this register," eax is the low 32 bits of rax not high. Other than that refer to the other comments on how writing eax zeroextends to rax
